# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key table Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to make this simple app where user enters data in text fields and it displays those data in table view. I have multiple files to define the structure of this app. But when I run the app, it crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key table.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011083934b **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dc3921e objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110839299 -[NSException raise] + 9
>       3   Foundation                          0x000000010d74926f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
>       4   UIKit                               0x000000010e2a24ef -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010e51679e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107de590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010e515122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010e2a8c21 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010e2a9543 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010e5291ca -[UITableViewController loadView] + 84
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010e2a9878 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010e2aa0cc -[UIViewController view] + 27
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010e173c51 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010e1743a2 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010e187cb5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
>       16  UIKit                               0x000000010e100c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
>       17  UIKit                               0x000000010e106de9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
>       18  UIKit                               0x000000010e103f69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
>       19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111ef7723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
>       20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111ef759c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
>       21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111ef7925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107de311 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107c359c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107c2a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107c2494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       26  UIKit                               0x000000010e1027e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
>       27  UIKit                               0x000000010e108964 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       28  Morning Star 2                      0x000000010d6531bf main + 111
>       29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011176668d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This is my EventBrain.swift File:

```
import Foundation

struct Event{

    var title:String?
    var location:String?

    init(tits: String, locs: String){
        self.title = tits
        self.location = locs
    }
}
```

This is my viewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtLocation: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtTime: UITextField!

    var eventsArray = [Event]()

    @IBAction func btnSave() {

        let event = Event(tits: txtTitle.text!, locs: txtLocation.text!)

        eventsArray.append(event)

    }
}
```

This is my EventsTable.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class EventsTable: UITableViewController {

    var tableData = ViewController()

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return tableData.eventsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomeCell

        cell.title.text = tableData.eventsArray[indexPath.row].title

        cell.location.text = tableData.eventsArray[indexPath.row].location

        return cell
    }
}
```

This is my customeCell.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class CustomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!

}
```

And finally here is my main.Storyboard:

[Main.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNRVO.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this happens when you connect an IBOutlet in InterfaceBuilder, then delete the code that defines the outlet.

The problem is that the Storyboard/XIB file tries to use KVC (Key Value Coding) to reference the property of the view controller for the outlet, but it's no longer there, so the KVC call crashes.

Look through your storyboards/xibs for a scene/view controller that has an outlet "table" that no longer exists.